# Footer line trouble

Tags: footer

[image]

As you can see in the image, the line at the footer collides with my text. How could I solve it? 
One way is to erase this command

```
\footrulewidth 0.4pt %---- no rule for foot
```

but I don't want to.

Something like that:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, letterpaper]{phstylee}

\begin{document} hola hola

\vspace{195mm}

hola

hola
\end{document}
```

I want to lower the line, but the space where it is written by the same.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! What have you done so far? Please add a minimal working example.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: You can slightly increase `\footskip`, e.g. with `geometry`.

Comment: Very nice, but where can the `phstylee` class be found?